# What test should I use to see correlations between overlapping groups and a score?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

To put it simply, I have the courses students have taken and scores on an exam. The students come from different course backgrounds. (Some have taken only course A some only D some A and D some A and B some B C and D etc etc)

What can test can I use to account for this?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for.

Comment: Okay, I want a test to see how the courses taken correlate with the scores obtained. I would have used an ANOVA but some students have taken more than one of the courses listed. Pretty much my issue is that I'm trying to compare groups while some people are in multiple groups.

Comment: OK, what confused me was your use of "correlation" which doesn't seem right. More below.

Comment: It would help if you'd further explain (without using any technical language if possible) what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to see if there is any relationship between the courses taken and the results on the exam.

Answer (score 1):

You want to see if grade relates to previous courses taken. That puts you in the regression group. But some students have taken one earlier course, some more than one. There are a couple options.

If the total number of courses that you are interested in is small and your sample is relatively large, then you could look at all combinations of courses. You list 4 courses, and if that reflects reality, then there are 16 combinations of courses. If you have enough people and they are spread over those combinations, you could look at all 16.

If there are many more courses, then you will have to combine them into groups. Also, if some of the combinations are rare then you may have to combine groups.

Another option is to ignore the multiplicity of courses and just look at the effect of each course.

The first option is similar to including all interactions. The second is like looking only at main effects.